# PHP-class with interface and error about abstract method

Tags: php, interface

I am working on a new widget for Tomato CMS and they use an interface:

```
interface Ad_Models_Interface_BannerPageAssoc
{
    ...

    /**
     * Get banner-page by Zone Id
     * 
     * @param int $zoneId Id of zone
     */
    public function getByZoneId($zoneId);
}
```

and another class that implements this interface:

```
class Ad_Models_Dao_Mysql_BannerPageAssoc extends Tomato_Model_Dao
implements Ad_Models_Interface_BannerPageAssoc
{

    public function getByZoneId($zoneId)
    {
      $sql  = sprintf("SELECT * FROM " . $this->_prefix . "ad_page_assoc");
      $rs   = mysql_query($sql);
      $rows = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
      }
      mysql_free_result($rs);
      return new Tomato_Model_RecordSet($rows, $this);
    }
}
```

When I make an object of this class and call the function, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class Ad_Models_Dao_Pdo_Mysql_BannerPageAssoc contains 1 abstract method and           must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Ad_Models_Interface_BannerPageAssoc::getByZoneId) in C:\xampp\htdocs\roepingen\application\modules\ad\models\dao\pdo\mysql\BannerPageAssoc.php on line 59

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ad_Models_Dao_Mysql_BannerPageAssoc` is not the same class as in the error:
`Ad_Models_Dao_Pdo_Mysql_BannerPageAssoc`.

Comment: This is indeed my fault ... Thanks for noticing :-)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem between your use of the keywords interface/abstract and extends/implements. You don't mention the class you actually get the error on, which is Ad_Models_Dao_Pdo_Mysql_BannerPageAssoc. That class must also implement the required methods if it implements Ad_Models_Interface_BannerPageAssoc. [Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) are treated differently than [abtract classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) in PHP.